# Problems splitting string at first empty space

Tags: android, string, split

I have a string which i need to split at the **first** empty space.

Somehow I can not get it to split, the string stays untouched.

Could somebody help?

String in question:

```
https://test.com/info/dsfs76/933/TT Maps 2015.12
```

**https://test.com/info/dsfs76/933/TT** and **Maps 2015.12** need to be 2 seperate parts which are added to an arraylist.

My code attempt:

```
if (str.contains(linkElem.getLinkAddress() + " ")) {
   String[] temp = str.split(" ");

   for (String temp : Arrays.asList(temp)) {
        arraytest.add(temp);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, there is no such String `strtemp`

Maybe you should be splitting `str` instead?

```
String[] temp = str.split(" ");
```

Comment: Hi blue, yeah sry I edited my code, it should be str what needs to be splitted but it doesn`t work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String tokenizer to do that like this:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(linkElem.getLinkAddress(), " ");

String a = st.nextToken();//string before " "
String b = st.nextToken();//string after " "
```

Comment: Hi, I get a "java.util.NoSuchElementException" on this line: String b = st.nextToken();

Comment: check whether the linkElem.getLinkAddress() is null,and whether it has  the empty spaces

Answer (score 0):

i know it is completely unelegant and dumb but it works %)

```
    String string = "https://test.com/info/dsfs76/933/TT Maps 2015.12";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean whiteSpaceFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) == ' ' && !whiteSpaceFound) {
            list.add(stringBuilder.toString());
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            whiteSpaceFound = true;
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append(string.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    if (whiteSpaceFound || list.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
```